# Doclink not opening in xpages

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

i am using this code it is show doclink but it is not opening it show some error.

```
var document1:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
var rtitem:NotesRichTextItem = document1.createRichTextItem("body");
document1.replaceItemValue("Form", "memo");
document1.replaceItemValue("SendTo", "lotusadm@san.org");
document1.replaceItemValue("Subject", "Rajesh");
rtitem.appendText("Some text here... ");
rtitem.addNewLine(2);
rtitem.appendText("NotesDocument.NotesURL");
rtitem.appendDocLink(document1, "Some comment text");
rtitem.addNewLine(2);
document1.save();
document1.send();
```

Error:- [image]
[image]

Please tell me how to open a doclink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to create a link to XPage's current document in your email.

You might have a data source defined in your XPage which is named "document1" as default

```xml
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument
        var="document1"
        action="editDocument"
        ...
    </xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>
```

Then, your code would look like this:

```js
var documentMail:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
var rtitem:NotesRichTextItem = documentMail.createRichTextItem("body");
documentMail.replaceItemValue("Form", "memo");
documentMail.replaceItemValue("SendTo", "lotusadm@san.org");
documentMail.replaceItemValue("Subject", "Rajesh");
rtitem.appendText("Some text here... ");
rtitem.addNewLine(2);
rtitem.appendText("NotesDocument.NotesURL");
rtitem.appendDocLink(document1.getDocument(), "Some comment text");
rtitem.addNewLine(2);
documentMail.save();
documentMail.send();
```

I changed email document's object name to `documentMail` and added `.getDocument()`.
 `document1.getDocument()` gives the data sources' document.